# problem with installing ros on mac osx lion (common_rosdeps)

Tags: macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using homebrew

when installing ros with,

`rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=electric&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"`

I got the following error.

```
Installing https://kforge.ros.org/common/rosdepcore common_rosdeps-1.0.2 to /Users/ze/ros/common_rosdeps
warning: kforge.ros.org certificate with fingerprint 9b:29:7b:22:3a:35:9c:e6:6c:ca:fe:b7:64:eb:1e:cd:bf:01:0a:92 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
pulling from https://kforge.ros.org/common/rosdepcore
searching for changes
no changes found
ERROR: Failed to install tree '/Users/ze/ros/common_rosdeps'
Update Failed of /Users/ze/ros/common_rosdeps
```

It seems to have something to do with 'common_rosdeps'. But I could not find any answer on the internet.

Any idea what to do?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12893/problem-with-installing-ros-on-mac-osx-lion-(common_rosdeps)/) by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2012-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like something happened when you were updating common_rosdeps from mercurial.  Try deleting the common_rosdeps folder and rerunning rosinstall.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok ... I just tried this now and it installed and built everything without a problem. Maybe there was an issue and it got fixed. Try again. :)

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on 2012-02-07**:
Just tried again, and it is the same. I can compile comm_deps with  rosmake individually, but with rosinstall, it says Failed to install tree '.......'

**Comment by [Ze JI](https://answers.ros.org/users/1235/ze-ji/) on 2012-02-06**:
Thanks. I will try again. There might be a problem with my mac, as I used macport (later removed), before installing homebrew.